# How to get data to other sheet if cell have number value only

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I have google sheet which have some data. like bellow

```
Sheet one

Column A |             | Column B
=================================
Hello    |             | *1*
World!   |             | p
Foo      |             | *3*
Bar      |             | L
Bar1     |             | *0*
```

Want data in sheet 2 only which have nubmers

```
   Sheet two

    Column A |             | Column B
    =================================
    Hello    |             | *1*
    Foo      |             | *3*
    Bar1     |             | *0*
```

Hope you understand what I want.

Comment: are those numeric values sorounded by asterix * or its just stackoverflow formatting?

Comment: yes it * includes with numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A1:B, ISNUMBER(Sheet1!B1:B*1))
```

[image: 0]

or maybe:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A1:B, ISNUMBER(REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet1!B1:B, "\*(\d+)\*")*1))
```

[image: 0]